# How to make a 2 dimentional background using a loop in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How do I make a board 8x8 2 dimentional like chess board background using loop in a fill.rect javascript function.

I tried creating the first loop however cant make it in 2 dimentioanal.
I tried having it in a modulus, seems hard for me to get the logic to iterate it alternately.

```
let canvas = document.getElementById('gameScreen');
let context = canvas.getContext("2d");

context.fillStyle = "#000";
for (let i = 0; i <= 160; i++) {
    context.fillRect(i, 0, 20, 20);
    i += 40;
}
```

There were no error message visible in the console.

The expected output should be an 8 by 8 alternately black and white square.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just came up with two loops, which draw every line and change the start point

```
let canvas = document.getElementById('gameScreen');
let context = canvas.getContext("2d");

context.fillStyle = "#000";

var  start = 0
for (let i = 0; i <= 160; i += 20) {
    for (let j = start; j <= 160; j += 40){
            context.fillRect(j, i, 20, 20);
    }
    start == 0 ? start += 20 : start = 0
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2n4xa873/1/

Comment: ```javascript

let canvas = document.getElementById('gameScreen');
let context = canvas.getContext("2d");

context.fillStyle = "#000";

var  start = 0
for (let i = 0; i <= 160; i++) {
    for (j = start; j <= 160; ++j) {
       // console.log("i and j", j,  i);
        context.fillRect(j, i, 20, 20);
        j += 40 - 1;
    }
    start == 0 ? start += 20 : start = 0;
    //console.log("start", start);
    i += 20 - 1;
}
```
I edited the solution. Thanks it works fine

Comment: BTW you can call a loop without the increment
`for (let i = 0; i <= 160; ) { 
for (j = start; j <= 160; ) {}}` so you don't need to subtract it when fillRect is called

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to use two for loops:

```
let SIZE = 20;
let on = true;
for (let x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
  on = !on;
  for (let y = 0; y < 8;  y++) {
    on = !on;
    if (on)  
      context.fillRect(x * SIZE, y * SIZE, SIZE, SIZE);
  }
}
```

Or more succinctly

```
let SIZE = 20;
for (let i = 0; i < 64; i+2) {
  let x = i % 8;
  let y = (i - x) / 8;
  context.fillRect(x * SIZE, y * SIZE, SIZE, SIZE);
}
```

Comment: `size != SIZE` <--

Comment: Hi junvar, It apears 8 alternate horizontal blocks of white and black rectangles.

Should I use modulos to divide the blocks divisible by 20 size?

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: For this to work `on = !on;` should also be added to the first *for*-loop. (Don't forget to add parentheses to the the *for*-loop since it's going to contain more than one statement.)

Comment: This problem was 4 months ago, and was resolved. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

Add the column index to row index, then take the the modulo of the sum. This also allows for easy customization.

```js
function createGameBoard(canvas, colors) {
  let context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  for (let row_index = 0; row_index < 8; row_index++) {
    for (let column_index = 0; column_index < 8; column_index++) {
      context.fillStyle = colors[(row_index + column_index) % colors.length];
      context.fillRect(column_index * 20, row_index * 20, 20, 20);
    }
  }  
}

createGameBoard(
  document.getElementById("gameScreen"),
  ["black", "white"]
);

createGameBoard(
  document.getElementById("gameScreen-alternative"),
  ["red", "green", "blue"]
);
```

```html
<canvas id="gameScreen" width="160" height="160"></canvas>
<canvas id="gameScreen-alternative" width="160" height="160"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks @3limin4tor This really helps :D